# Accept-Language header - prefer some language but accept all

Tags: rest, http-headers

I investigated postman's request headers and they have this as an accept-language value

```
 'accept: '*/*'
 'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
```

so I also used this in my app.

Is this enough if I want the server to accept English but also accept any other language besides English?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's analyse it one after the other.

`Accept` [header](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.3.2) is to

> specify certain media types which are acceptable for the response

So right now you are accepting all media types (`text/plain`, `text/html` and so on) and it has nothing to do with language.

`Accept-language` [restricts](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.3.5)

> the set of natural languages that are **preferred** as a
> response to the request

And

> if the header field is present in a request and none of the available
> representations for the response have a matching language tag, the
> **origin server can either disregard the header field by treating the
> response as if it is not subject to content negotiation or honor the
> header field by sending a 406 (Not Acceptable) response**.  However, **the
> latter is not encouraged**, as doing so can prevent users from accessing
> content that they might be able to use (with translation software, for
> example).

Theoretically `406` response code is possible (but it's unlikely), so better specify your header as `en-US,en;q=0.8,*;q=0.7`

Comment: thanks for the explanation. Can you confirm if my understanding is correct...  *;q=0.7 means "I am accepting any other languages, but in low priority unlike English" which is q=0.8?